# How to make an if statement change a text field in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield, stringwithformat

Okay, so I'm trying to make this action change a user-editable textfield if the textfield is empty. This is the code i'm using right now, but it won't work:

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]) {
    [o1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
```

Anybody know why? I did this as well:

```
UITextField *textField;
```

Is that necessary?

UPDATE:
I just realized I should have put this in here earlier, but it's for ios, not mac. Sorry!

Comment: Is the textfield linked in IB?

Comment: My bad, it's for ios, unless I'm supposed to link it there even on ios...

Comment: Yes, you have to link it in IB unless you add the text field through code (`[myView addSubview:textField];`).

Comment: Also, you should probably name it something other that "textField".

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make the if statement work for all of the textfields instead of have to write one for each. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat convoluted - just test like so:

```
if ([myTextField length] == 0) myTextField.text = @"1";
```

You need to declare myTextField in the interface like so:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

then link it in IB. You could make it a property to simplify memory management.